# как вывести два числа из таблицы? python, SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

есть код:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT cash, bitcoin FROM users WHERE name = ? and id = ?", [first_name, ids])
                result = cursor.fetchone()
                if not result:
                    send('Пользователь не найден!')
                else:
                    send(str(result)[0] + 'монет\n' + str(result)[1] + 'биткоинов')
```

он должен выводить 300 монет и 2 биткойна (результат из таблицы)

но когда я пытаюсь получить два числа (они записаны как (300, 2))
то он не берёт их как элемент из списка, а как элемент строки:
(монет
3биткоинов
**(3**00, 2)

как взять элемент, возвращаемый fetchone?

PS.я не могу брать 2 fetchone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем вы делаете `str(result)`, превращая весь `result` в строку? Сначала берите элементы `tuple` `result`, а потом, если нужно, превращайте их в строки:

```
send(str(result[0]) + 'монет\n' + str(result[1]) + 'биткоинов')
```

Comment: это не tuple, а строка почему то, если бы это был кортеж, то я бы просто взял его элемент

Comment: @ЕгорКолесников Погодите, вы пробовали мой вариант кода, вы видели, что он отличается от вашего?

Comment: да, спасибо, всё работает